# Stack vectors of different lengths in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensor, zero-padding

How can I stack vectors of different length in tensorflow, e.g. from

```
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 9, 1, 1]
[6, 2]
```

get zero-padded matrix

```
[1, 3, 5, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 9, 1, 1]
[6, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Vector count is known at definition time, but their lengths are not. Vectors are produced using `tf.where(condition)`

Comment: [tf.pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) and [tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) should help.

Comment: @gobrewers14 problem with tf.pad and tf.stack is that length of the padding is not known at definition time, so I can't allocate tensor for padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is like:

```
In [11]: v1 = [1, 3, 5]
In [12]: v2 = [2, 3, 9, 1, 1]
In [14]: v3 = [6, 2]

In [38]: max_len = max(len(v1), len(v2), len(v3))
In [39]: pad1 = [[0, max_len-len(v1)]]
In [40]: pad2 = [[0, max_len-len(v2)]]
In [41]: pad3 = [[0, max_len-len(v3)]]

# pads 0 to original vectors up to `max_len` length
In [42]: v1_padded = tf.pad(v1, pad1, mode='CONSTANT')
In [43]: v2_padded = tf.pad(v2, pad2, mode='CONSTANT')
In [44]: v3_padded = tf.pad(v3, pad3, mode='CONSTANT')


In [53]: res = tf.stack([v1_padded, v2_padded, v3_padded], axis=0)

In [56]: res.eval()
Out[56]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 9, 1, 1],
       [6, 2, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

To make it work with `N` vectors efficiently, you should probably use a `for` loop to prepare the `pad` variables for all the vectors and the padded vectors subsequently. And, finally use `tf.stack` to stack these padded vectors along the `0`th axis to get your desired result.

---

**P.S.**: You can get the length of the vectors dynamically once they are obtained from `tf.where(condition)`.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it seems that it is not possible to allocate tensor of shape defined by tf.variable. E.g. pad1 = tf.zeros(max_len - tf.size(v1)) doesn't work.

Comment: @DikobrAz `pad1` should not be all zeros. It should be the number representing how many zeros to pad and in which dimension. For more information about how padding is done, please see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad

Comment: Maybe can you add more code about how you get those vectors?

Comment: You're right @kmario23, padding with pad1 = [[0, max_len - tf.size(v1)]] works!

Comment: @kmario23 please how to add mask those padded inputs ?